# Toolbar menu item not clickable on android 4.4 (19)

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I have a Android app for Android sdk version 23. Now I try to make it available for user using versions 19 to 23. 
All is working fine expect the toolbar in the head of the app. I can't click an menu item. Nothing happend when I click. Also if I insert Log.v() there is no message in the debug view.

What can I do?

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            doRefreshGames(item);
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.action_rss){
            Intent rssIntent = new Intent(AmericanFootball.this, AmericanFootballRSS.class);
            //if you need to pass data:
            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putString("myKey", "comeon");
            rssIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
            startActivity(rssIntent);
        }

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Did you extend your Activity from AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: Yes I extend my Activity from AppCompatActivity, is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue too. This was because I was using `CoordinatorLayout` which is a super-powered FrameLayout and thus was Overlaying the toolbar thus blocking interaction with the toolbar. I solved the issue by replacing the `CoordinatorLayout` with a `LinearLayout` and giving it a vertical orientation. 
You can also solve the issue by setting the `toolbar` position in relation to the parent as described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042004/overlapping-views-in-coordinatorlayout)

Comment: alternatively, you can add the AppBarLayout after the fragment in the CoordinatorLayout.