# How can 'keyline' LayoutParams of CoordinatorLayout be used?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-layoutparams

According to the documentation:

> The index of the horizontal keyline specified to the parent CoordinatorLayout that this child should align relative to.

Can anyone explain how the 'keyline' works with an example?

Comment: Couldn't find how it works in CoordinatorLayout, but for an explanation of what keylines are for there is this link: https://material.io/design/layout/spacing-methods.html#spacing

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts:

1. setting the keylines for the `CoordinatorLayout`, and
2. referencing a keyline in a child view.

For the former, create an int array resource and reference it from the `keylines` attribute of the `CoordinatorLayout`. For example:

res/values/arrays.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="keylines">
        <item>16</item>
        <item>72</item>
        <item>160</item>
        <item>256</item>
        <item>320</item>
    </array>
    ...
</resources>
```

activity_main.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:keylines="@array/keylines"
    ...
```

Then, to position a child view horizontally relative to a keyline, set its [`layout_keyline`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams#keyline) attribute to the index into the `keylines` array resource. For example, to set a button on keyline 2 (position at 160dp):

activity_main.xml

```xml
    ...
    <Button
        app:layout_keyline="2"
```

Positioning relative to the keyline is defined by the `layout_gravity` attribute. For a button, this will position the button's text, so if you want to use gravity to position the button, wrap it in another view (e.g. `FrameLayout`) and set the keyline for the parent view rather than the `Button`:

```xml
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        app:layout_keyline="2"
        ...>

        <Button
            ...
```

Keylines let you position a child view horizontally within a `CoordinatorLayout`. The vertical positioning is determined by the vertical margins & padding and is relative to the top of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Note that if an `anchor` is also set for the child view, its keyline will be ignored.

If you're curious about the layout logic, it's implemented by `onLayoutChild()` and `layoutChildWithKeyline()` in [`CoordinatorLayout`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/src/main/java/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout.java).