# How to achieve overlapping in CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have used CoordinatorLayout for getting Appbar + RecyclerView scroll behavior. But I'm not able to achieve overlapping of Appbar over the RecyclerView within this CoordinatorLayout. I have tried using negative margins which works but I don't know if that is a good practice. Is there any other way to achieve this?

The following code is the original xml without negative margins:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ...
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            ...
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**[Edit]** I tried encapsulating Appbar + RecyclerView within RelativeLayout before putting them in CoordinatorLayout (see [Overlapping views in coordinatorlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042004/overlapping-views-in-coordinatorlayout)) but that just breaks the "hide appbar on scroll" behavior.

Comment: please add XML and code.

Comment: Check if you have added something like |app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"|, try removing it.
Otherwise, please do share XML and code.

Comment: @TanveerMunir Added the xml

Comment: @sagargurtu please have to look my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is I am using this Like this

**XML:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You are using `layout_scrollFlags` according to your requirements.

Please have to look this [URL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams)